# How to bridge a virtual interface inside docker container?

Tags: linux, docker, networking

Let me re-organised the question. I have used a similar docker-compose yaml file as below.

```
version: "3"
services:
  app:
    build: ./app
    networks:
      - frontend
 
networks:
  frontend:
     driver: bridge
     ipam:
       config:
         - subnet: 172.38.3.0/24
```

A network interface eth0 will be created automatically inside the dock container APP. I can connect to the network of the host through eth0.

Now I want to create other virtual network interfaces inside the docker container APP, such as veth1, veth2. I want to let the packets through veth1/veth2 can access the host network. Like the below,

```
ping -I veth1 host-network-ip
```

by the way, I have tried to define one more network in the yaml and attached to docker container APP. but unfortunately, the network interface name eth1 inside docker container could not be customized. I need to specify the network interface name.

Is it possible to let it work? if yes, can you please help to explain how to do? Thank you very much!

Comment: Please start with the [tour] and read [ask]. Concerning your question, start with `docker network help` to get an overview of what features Docker offers for network management. Also, you seem to describe a so-called "XY problem".

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I have updated my question, hope it's clear now.